# z-index troubles, advanced z-indexing

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

I'm looking to figure out the z-indexing for the floating social bar at this link (scroll down the page for it to show up):

http://dailycaller.com/2013/01/25/herman-cain-explains-why-he-wont-run-for-georgia-senate-seat/

Currently, the way that I have the containing div set, in order to be in the fixed position to the side, is at 100% with a fixed div. This is covering the content so the links in the content are not target-able.

The problem is the facebook like button. How do I get the z-indexing set correctly so that the facebook box shows up on top but the hyperlinks in the content are target-able?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps set the width of the sidebar container instead of making it 100% and then make use of

```
overflow: visible;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CFCDS/3/

(excuse my margins—they are just there to get everything to look a bit more like you had it.)